# How to set module name in SQLAlchemy and cx_Oracle with create_engine()?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

In SQLAlchemy I create an engine with :

```
engine = create_engine(url="oracle+cx_oracle://user:xxxx@tns")
```

In cx_Oracle, I would create a connection with :

```
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user="user", password="xxxx", dsn="tns")
```

I can then set the module with [Connection.module](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/connection.html#Connection.module) attribute which tags appropriately when looking at v$session table.

```
conn.module = "MyModule"
```

Is there a way to set the Oracle session module name to an `sqlalchemy.engine.Engine` once it is created with `create_engine`?

Comment: You can access the raw cx_Oracle connection directly See https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#working-with-the-dbapi-cursor-directly  Another potential way would be to use something like https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/oracle.html#using-oracle-database-resident-connection-pooling-drcp (without the DRCP bits, if you're not using DRCP) and set the attribute in `creator()` after the `pool.aquire()` call.

Comment: thanks @ChristopherJones for pointing me in the right direction! I ended up using hook `DialectEvents.do_connect()` hook. https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html?highlight=create_engine#sqlalchemy.create_engine.params.creator which fit the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `DialectEvents.do_connect()` [hook](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/events.html#sqlalchemy.events.DialectEvents.do_connect) which worked nicely for me.

```py
import cx_Oracle
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, event


engine = create_engine(url="oracle+cx_oracle://user:xxxx@tns")
@event.listens_for(engine, "do_connect")
def receive_do_connect(dialect, conn_rec, cargs, cparams):
    """listen for the 'do_connect' event"""
    connection = cx_Oracle.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
    connection.module = "MyModule"
    return connection
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing.  If you (or other readers) are handling multiple users in a service or web app, then the recommendation would always be to use an Oracle session pool which has some dead connection detection features, and supports other Oracle features for high availability.